# Need icon ideas to indicate "crane not working "

Tags: icon

I overlapped the below icon on top of the vehicle but still the user feels like the vehicle is prohibited rather than not working/operational. [image: not working] Is there any other way to design. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a [warning icon](https://www.google.com/search?q=warning+icon&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWrLL87MXPAhVCQBQKHVcmCCoQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=689)?

Comment: Maybe something based on the lock-out tags your particular group uses?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In cases like this it's worth brainstorming a bit first. After and during it might be a good idea to see what others have done with tools like [the noun project](https://thenounproject.com/) (and search for [broken](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=broken) and [crane](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=crane) for example). Then just integrate the ideas by combining things, here I'm combing crane, broken bone and typical warning sign. YMMV.

[image]

**Image 1**: Quick example combining 3 different concepts

Obviously you need to do your own thinking here and my example is very quick but shows how you could approach the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, a line drawing of a crane with a broken boom. [Or a crane with a broken leg.](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fimage.shutterstock.com%2Fz%2Fstock-vector-crane-patient-with-a-broken-knee-sitting-on-a-chair-in-the-waiting-room-at-the-doctor-110606414.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fpic-110606414%2Fstock-vector-crane-patient-with-a-broken-knee-sitting-on-a-chair-in-the-waiting-room-at-the-doctor.html&docid=y7sgjVBklyItcM&tbnid=GJl7n_CV0rxALM%3A&w=950&h=1600&bih=923&biw=1664&ved=0ahUKEwjt_qa2x8bPAhWlDsAKHX9FDP4QMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8) (SCNR).

Comment: I'd be concerned that this looks like "warning, crane", with only a very small amount area showing "broken".  A bit of dirt or wear and it goes away completely.   https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=crane&i=490256 (give it a single-line "arm") with a large https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=broken&i=126507 style break?

Comment: @Yakk its a demo not supposed to be used. It is intentionally quickly done, point is i'm combining items and ideas on lists of things. Its a first sketch that's all i used a whopping 3 minutes to draw the image.

Comment: (1) this means "hook not working", not, "crane not working".  in any event: (2) the "break" indication is, absolutely and definitely, too small by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I know you just intended this to be a brainstorm example, but I can't help but try to misinterpret the sign on principle.  "Warning: coathangers may be untrustworthy!"

Comment: @JoeBlow Sure. That is life, you can not make a perfect icon without somebody disagreeing, pretty sure the symbol means something else in a far away place. Making a image is just a first step in design it still needs to be evaluated, tweaked etc. But like in code premature optimisation is a problem. Perfect is the enemy of done. Like i said i dont expect anybody to use this particular icon.

Comment: @joojaa - quite right!!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe display a broken crane, like you would display a broken heart?
Or a large bandaid icon, accompanied with a word/text?

Comment: cracked in half with a plume of smoke should convey the idea

Answer (score 3):

If you can use colours I'd say make a green crane for OK, a red one (optionally with a line through it) for forbidden and a grey one for 'not available'.

Comment: Don't neglect the possibility that the users who see the icon may be color blind, especially as red-green color blindness is the most common form.

Comment: Yes, there is that.